# Why does std::vector<double> v{unsigned int} does not choose a valid constructor?

Tags: c++11, compilation

I have a question concerning the following c++ program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    unsigned int i{5};
    std::vector<double> v{i};
    for(auto d : v){
            std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

g++ version 4.9.3 and g++ version 5.4 compile and generate the warning:

```
test.cpp:6:25: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘i’ from ‘int’ to ‘double’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
std::vector<double> v{i};
```

which I can understand, as according to the specification, the compiler wants to use the initializer list constructor of std::vector :

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
>   the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>   the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
>   elements of the initializer list.

But what I can not understand is that clang version 3.8 fails to compile the program, with the same error as the warning above. I would expect that in this case the initializer-list constructor is not viable (at least clang rejects it) and the "intended" constructor of std::vector should be used instead.

My question: Narrowing conversions are syntax errors in the program and hence (in my understanding) the constructor of std::vector should be used that creates a std::vector of size 5. **So why are the compilers ignoring the constructor that would lead to a valid program?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[dcl.init.list]/3** Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

The necessity of narrowing conversion doesn't render a constructor non-viable. Instead, it participates in the overload resolution normally, and then, if it happens to be chosen, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand your cited sentence and why it is usefull to do so. If we have chosen a constructor, this is the best one (the constructor that fits best according to the given type(s)). And if now a narrowing conversion happenes, we report an error. But I think that this assumption (found constructor is the best one according to the types) is violated due to the two phase selection cited in my question. The types for the intuitive constructor fit better that the ones for the initializer list. Do you expect this behaviour to be changed in later versions of c++?